# After upgrading to to 1.9 from 1.7, new order not saving

Tags: magento

After upgrading to to 1.9.1 from 1.7, new order not saving at all. Few customer told they have paid through sage pay but in magento admin we can't see any customer or sale in graph.

Also onepage checkout was not working but after we reselect different paypal method(express method) then it is at least redirecting to paypal but omitting step 6. It seems there is something in step 6(which does not let redirect to paypal).

Because nothing has been saved about order we have a big issue, as we don't know for what item they have paid for? Also customer or we not receiving any email after order placement.

Anyone experiencing same problem?

Answer (score 0):

***For your payment issues:***

I assume you can see every payment in your sage panel thus you know if the order is payed for or not? But Magento should first save the order to the DB and then process payment, if the order isn't saved payment wont process.

***For the order not saving and no emails issues:***

1.9 uses formkeys a lot throughout the template where 1.7 doesn't. Formkeys are unique numbers added to hidden fields in forms.  Here is some info about what formkeys are and why they should be used: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753

For instance, a lot of controllers are now starting with this

```
if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
    $this->_redirect('*/*');
    return;
}
```

This is where most migrations from 1.7 to 1.9 go wrong. 
My suggestion, put the default 1.9 RWD template on and see if the problem still persist. It it doesn't you are probabbly missing some formkeys somewhere in your template.

You can get these keys by the follow 2 methods:

**Proper way trough layout and block injecting**

Add this to layout xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <block name="formkey" type="core/template" template="core/formkey.phtml" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

add this in the forms where you need the key

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

**Quick and dirty way**

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. I ll look into this. i am new to magento so need some study to apply these changes. please answer me if i ask further question later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, got things up and running?